# Problem with javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am using particular JavaScript to check if the value is stored in database... I am getting problem its not showing status as it hang up after loading image. WHile if I use same javascript with other file its working good. Everything thing is alright that is query on other page showalbumstatus.php

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function showalbumstatus(name) {
    document.getElementById("albumstatus").innerHTML = "<img src= photos/loading.gif>";
    xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp == null) {
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
        return;
    }
    var url = "showalbumstatus.php";
    url = url + "?";
    url = url + "album=" + name;
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById("albumstatus").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
}
```

I am using onblur command on page `onblur="showalbumstatus(form1.name.value);"`

I checked the using JavaScript Console of Chrome exact error is:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
stateChanged**

Comment: I would switch to jQuery. All of this is simplified and more manageable.

Comment: Sorry ..please explain detailed.

Comment: @Aditii: If you can use a code library, **any** of the myriad of JavaScript libraries available may be helpful to use. At the same time, nothing wrong with writing your own code either.

Comment: I am new with all javascript. Can u please explain what is that 'or how can I modify this..

Comment: @Aditii: There are many code libraries available that have pre-written JavaScript code availalbe. They make some of the more challenging aspects of using JavaScript and the DOM a bit easier. AJAX requests are one example. Would you consider using such a library, or are you under a requirement to not use one?

Comment: @patrick : I am not getting what u exactly you want to say. as I found code on net it was showing me ajax code. I have `function GetXmlHttpObject()` written in this file n I think that is part of AJAX.

Why the code is running successful with other file of checking status? While not working with this particular file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check whether `document.getElementById("albumstatus")` is `null` -- and if so, you got the problem first hand.

The error you're getting is a `TypeError` -- which means that the type of a variable does NOT support the operation you are performing on it.

Also try these...

`onblur="showalbumstatus(form1.name.value);"` -- this is an **extremely BAD** way to register event handlers -- do this...

```
elem.onblur = function() {
 // event handler code goes here...
};
```

`var url = "showalbumstatus.php";` -- instead of this, try the absolute URL like this..

`var url = "http://example.com/showalbumstatus.php";`
and see if it works.

Also, inspect the error console for the response you're getting from the server for the ajax call -- see if that's alright.

Finally, i have to point out, ultimately you're going to want to ditch this way of doing ajax in your JS apps -- go learn some platform lib -- jQuery, Prototype, MooTools.

Answer (score 3):

Are you are willing to use any of the javascript libraries. Mind you, its a giant leap of faith. You may get confused at the syntax initially. You would be good if you note that its just another JavaScript library and keep learning JavaScript.

Here is how your code looks like in jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#albumstatus").html("<img src= photos/loading.gif>");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'showalbumstatus.php',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: '{}',
        success: function(response) {
            $("#albumstatus").html(response);
        },
        error: function(a, b, c) {
            $("#albumstatus").text("Error!");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks... I will learn and try this soon.

but please explain with my error. What sort of error is this how can I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Put an alert in showalbumstatus to see if onblur event is being fired or not. It is also possible that event is firing but evaluation of form1.name.value is failing with error. So you might want to our an alert there as well for testing.
2. If all turns out to be well with your event handler, next thing is to check whether stateChanged is called or not.

The best way of debugging javascript is to use firebug (an extenstion for FireFox).

Comment: I checked with javascript console of CHROME...

ERROR IS "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
stateChanged"

Comment: @Shamaila Chrome works perfectly well for basic JS like this. CSS, on the other hand, it is Firebug or bust.

Comment: @cwallenpoole. Yes chrome developer tools offer many of the functions that firebug supports. For Aditii case, both must be good enough.

Comment: @Aditii, you are setting innerHTML property of a variable whose value is `null`. `document.getElementById("albumstatus")` must be returning `null`.